# Solr 4.10.2 MySQL import fails with java.io.EOFException

Tags: mysql, solr

I'm trying to migrate a server with Solr 4.7.2 on it. I have a Solr 4.10.2 with 4 cores running which is the new machine. I have an importer running on the old machine that poses no problem. However, when trying to run the importer on the new machine, I get a

> java.io.EOFException : Can not read response from server.Expected to read 848 bytes, read 576 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

I've thrown some extra parameters into the data-config.xml in the hopes it would fix the problem, but to no avail :

```
defaultFetchSize="30"
useCursorFetch="true" 
autoReconnect="true"       
tcpKeepAlive="true" 
connectionTimeout="120000"
stream="true"
```

The file syntax of the data import must be correct, since the import runs fine on exactly the same MySQL table with less records in it on the same machine.

I've been trying to debug this for hours and hours now, and can't find the solution. Can anyone help me with any pointers on how to properly find the cause for this?

Comment: try setting connectionTimeout="0"..

Comment: That throws exactly the same error, doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to MySQL. When I connect the new Solr instance remotely to the old database server, the index runs fine. Any suggestions there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually had to change my.cnf for the new MySQL server. For some reason the new one (also 5.5.43) closed the connection after timeout. I changed the settings for timeout in MySQL and now it indexes correctly, for about 21 minutes.

I wished tomcat7 and solr made that more clear in their error log.